# Euler's criterion with negative $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In this version of Euler's criterion it states that if $a$ is a positive integer and $p$ is an odd prime such that it does not divide $a$ then the Legendre symbol of $a$ with respect to $p$ is congruent to $a$ to the power of $(p-1)/2$ modulo $p$, 
but why does $a$ have to be a positive integer, why can't it be negative? I can't see a reason, because with modular arithmetic you could just swap the negative $a$ with a positive value.
Here is a link:
[Euler's criterion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-criterion/)

Comment: Welcome. There are complementary formulas for $\left(\dfrac{-1}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{2}{p}\right)$ and you do have $\left(\dfrac{-a}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)$.

Comment: But, would I not get the same result by just using Euler's criterion. For example if a = - 1, assuming p is an odd prime, and doesn't divide a?

Comment: You do have the formula $\left(\dfrac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}$. If odd prime $p=4n+1$ then $-1$ is a square modulo $p$. If $p=4n+3$ then $-1$ is not.

Comment: I would not trust a site like that.  Their [Legendre symbol](https://brilliant.org/wiki/legendre-symbol/) page has the correct version, but their Euler criterion page has this meaningless restriction.